# Connecting to a CUPS server

Tags: printing

I'm probably missing something entirely obvious, but here goes anyway.

I'm trying to connect my Ubuntu desktop to a CUPS print server. I go to printers menu, click connect and enter the server address. All the printers connected to the server show up in the printers menu so everything seems to work. However, when  I try to print from some application (say, document reader), I only see the local printers in the printing menu without an option to use one of the server printers.

How can I make the printers shared from the server to appear when I print from some application?